# Zend Framework buitl-in ubuntu 9.10 server

Tags: ubuntu, zend-framework

anyone know if the Zend Framework is built in Ubuntu 9.10 server edition ? if yes, how to check it from command line?

Answer (score 2):

It is `apt-cache search zend-framework`, but it's not the most recent version.

PS: Doesn't this question belong to serverfault?

Comment: this is wat i get :

libzend-framework-php - a simple, straightforward, open-source software framework for PHP 5
zend-framework - a simple, straightforward, open-source software framework for PHP 5
zend-framework-bin - a simple, straightforward, open-source software framework for PHP 5

Comment: What I get from your question is: "Is Zend Framework available in the ubuntu 9.10 package repository". So when doing a search it turns out there is.

To install it do `sudo apt-get install libzend-framework-php` which will probably install it to `/usr/share/php`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check by visiting packages.ubuntu.com.

Here is a [list of packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zend&searchon=names&suite=karmic) with the name **zend** on **karmic**.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the Framework is shipped by default. You can try to do something like

```
locate Zend
```

or run the zf tool from your bash (zf.sh) , if it returns something the framework is ready.

Comment: I get the following :

/usr/share/doc/libzend-framework-php/demos/Zend<br />
/usr/share/doc/libzend-framework-php/demos/Zend/Feeds<br />
/usr/share/doc/libzend-framework-php/demos/Zend/Gdata<br />
/usr/share/doc/libzend-framework-php/demos/Zend/Locale<br />
/usr/share/doc/libzend-framework-php/demos/Zend/Mail<br />
/usr/share/doc/libzend-framework-php/demos/Zend/OpenId<br />
/usr/share/doc/libzend-framework-php/demos/Zend/Pdf<br />
/usr/share/doc/libzend-framework-php/demos/Zend/ProgressBar<br />
.<br />
.<br />
.
'any more listing'


Is this mean I have Zend installed ?

Comment: <br /> is the new line